# ¿Cómo reparar tablas en uso?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, php5

Tengo una tabla en *PhpMyAdmin*:

[image: Error en tabla]

En la imagen se puede ver el siguiente error:

> (!) #1932 Table `evocar.chores` doesn't exist in engine

El problema es que no puedo acceder a dicha tabla porque está **en uso**, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Tabla en uso]

¿Cómo puedo repararla?

Comment: a que te refieres con reparar, cual es el fallo?

Comment: Pues sale un error al dar click a la tabla y necesito modificar la estructura de esta

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva:

http://www.kroatoan.es/trucos-y-solucines/error-mysql-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine/

Explicacion de la Url:

Tras investigar un poco resulta que en principio no es una tabla sino una vista. En raras ocasiones un error de mysql bloquea la vista y aparece en el sistema como una tabla “en uso”. Sin embargo, al no ser una tabla real el sistema lo interpreta como una tabla corrupta y no permite operar con ella.

El principal problema es que nos impide realizar un mysql_dump o una copia de seguridad que no vaya tabla a tabla. Especialmente duro si no tienes una copia de seguridad relativamente reciente.
La solución más sencilla que he encontrado y que funciona sin borrar la base de datos ni reiniciar el servicio mysql es eliminar o renombrar los archivos de mysql directamente. Para ello debemos acceder por ssh al servidor y buscar los fichoros .frm que mysql guarda de cada tabla. Esto depende de cada sistema pero en el caso de una instalación Centos con Plesk los encontramos en /var/lib/mysql.

Estos archivos siguen la nomenclatura /var/lib/mysql//.frm. Debemos buscar el archivo de la tabla en cuestión y renombrarlo o eliminarlo. En mi caso lo renombre añadiéndole la extensión .bck por si me fuese necesario recuperarla (que no fue el caso).

Una vez hecho esto debe de haber desaparecido al hacer SHOW TABLES. En caso de que sigan apareciendo puede ser por un tema de cache interna de mysql. Proba usando un FLUSH TABLES por si eso lo soluciona.

Comment: Gracias por colaborar. Si se elimina el archivo ya no aparece la tabla, si lo restauro la tabla sigue  “en uso”, si entendí bien quieres que lo elimine y cree nuevamente la tabla, pero al hacer eso dice: “#1050 - La tabla ‘chores’ ya existe.” Así que también hay que eliminar el archivo  .ibd y detener MySQL y volver a iniciarlo para poder recrear la tabla, si no se tiene una copia de los datos se perderán ya que la idea es eliminar la tabla y el error para volverla a crear.